# Modify url and update with anather url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below url

Input
url1 = https://www.example1.com/xyz/abc/123

I need modified above url and replace only domain to https://www.modifiedexample.com/

Output url2= https://www.modifiedexample.com/xyz/abc/123

This should work in all the browser

How to achieve this in Javasript in simple and efficient way

Comment: This didnt fix issue for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API:

```js
const url = new URL('https://www.example1.com/xyz/abc/123');

url.hostname = 'www.modifiedexample.com';

console.log(url.href); // https://www.modifiedexample.com/xyz/abc/123
```